# Get correct week Start date and end date when monday , tuesday falls in last year last week

Tags: java

I am getting week number and year from DB(using function DATE_PART('week',alarm_date - (interval '1 days') * 0) AS week, DATE_PART('year',alarm_date) AS yearNo , ISO compliant) and on the basis of week number and year i want to calculate weekStartDate and weekEndDate between user provided startdate and end date with week start date for example {"startDate":"2021-12-28","endDate":"2022-01-06","weekStartDay":"Sunday"}

```
private String getWeek(LocalDate startTime, LocalDate endTime, int yearNo, int weekNumber, int weekStartDay){
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        // make it ISO compliant since postgres is using ISO time to calculate week number
        cal.setMinimalDaysInFirstWeek(4);
        cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, yearNo);
        cal.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, weekNumber);

        //ISO week starts on Monday and ends on Sunday
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, weekStartDay);//  weekStartDay configurabale, as per 
 //user input Calendar.SUNDAY or Calendar.MONDAY or Calendar.TUEDAY; etc
        String weekStartDate = sdf.format(cal.getTime());

        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 6);
        String weekEndDate = sdf.format(cal.getTime());

        LocalDate weekStart = LocalDate.of(Integer.valueOf(weekStartDate.substring(0, 4)),
                Integer.valueOf(weekStartDate.substring(5, 7)), Integer.valueOf(weekStartDate.substring(8)));

        if(weekStart.isBefore(startTime)) {
            weekStart = startTime;
        }

        LocalDate weekEnd = LocalDate.of(Integer.valueOf(weekEndDate.substring(0, 4)),
                Integer.valueOf(weekEndDate.substring(5, 7)), Integer.valueOf(weekEndDate.substring(8)));
        if(weekEnd.isAfter(endTime)) {
            weekEnd = endTime;
        }

        String weekStr = weekStart.toString()+"_"+weekEnd.toString();
        return weekStr;
    }
```

But when weekStartDay falls in lastweek of previous year then it gives the wrong vale of weekStartDate and weekStartEnd so please suggest me how to set yearnumber in java

Comment: Did you copy parts of this code from different sources?

Comment: @Tom This is my own code that i use in my development where i am showing user record on graph chart week basis

Comment: @avanishrai , what is the expected result for the input provided! Would it be 2nd Jan and 9th Jan 2022 ?

Comment: If this is your own code, why do Mix old Java Date/Calenders with the newer java.time? What was the advantage for you to do that?

Comment: @Ramachandran.A.G  expected result is 28-12-2021 TO 01-01-2022 && 02-01-2022 to 06-01-2022

Comment: @Tom i am not getting exactly could you plz explain more, startdate and endDate comes from another API in forms of LocalDate and alrmDate in Date format

Comment: trying to understand the problem, but it is too much effort. Can you provide some  code to reproduce the problem? For example code that you would write in main method.

Comment: What did you mean by “ISO compliant”? A standard ISO 8601 week always starts on a Monday, ends on a Sunday. So your first day of week parameter makes no sense. Your entire Question is confusing and unfocused. A rewrite is in order. And study existing Questions and Answers *before* posting.  Week dates topic has been addressed many many times.

Comment: I strongly recommend that you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Calnedar`. Those classes are troublesome and long outdated. In addition to `LocalDate` use `WeekFields` also from java.time, the modern Java date and time API.

Comment: Get `weekStart` as `LocalDate.ofYearDay(yearNo, 20) .with(WeekFields.ISO.weekOfWeekBasedYear(), weekNumber) .with(DayOfWeek.MONDAY);`. For 2020 and week 1 this will be 2019-12-30. The last day of the week is always just 6 days later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avinash, not the full answer but in-line with what Tom mentioned. A lot of convinient date time API's can be used since Java-8. Please feel free to customize this approach for the exact logic you may need

```
    import java.time.DayOfWeek;
    import java.time.temporal.ChronoField;
    import java.time.temporal.IsoFields;
    import static java.time.temporal.IsoFields.WEEK_OF_WEEK_BASED_YEAR;
    import java.time.LocalDate;
    import java.time.YearMonth;
    import java.time.temporal.TemporalAdjusters;
    
    public class SO75013931 {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println(getWeekStart(LocalDate.parse("2021-12-28"),DayOfWeek.SUNDAY));
            System.out.println(getWeekEnd(LocalDate.parse("2021-12-28"),DayOfWeek.SUNDAY));
        }
    
        //28-12-2021 TO 01-01-2022 && 02-01-2022 to 06-01-2022
        private static String getWeekStart(LocalDate localDate, DayOfWeek weekStartDay) {
            LocalDate weekStart = localDate.with(TemporalAdjusters.previous(weekStartDay));
            return weekStart.isBefore(localDate) ? localDate.toString(): weekStart.toString();
        }
        private static String getWeekEnd(LocalDate localDate, DayOfWeek weekStartDay) {
            LocalDate weekEnd = localDate.with(TemporalAdjusters.next(weekStartDay.minus(1)));
            return weekEnd.isBefore(localDate) ? localDate.toString(): weekEnd.toString();
        }
    }

This would give

    2021-12-28
    2022-01-01

Again, the idea was to recommend usage of these API's as opposed to older util API's
```

Comment: appreciate your responce but my requirement is On the basis of weekNumber and Year to find out week group(between start date and end date) , from DB i got the records(that contains weeknumber and year number ofthat record) between startdate and enddate